# Redirect to a new url structure - same domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

So I recently moved my website from an old CMS to WordPress.
Re-imported 3000+ to WP and now all the old urls are 404.

I would like to **301 redirect** all my posts within the htaccess.
*The domain is still the same*. I just need to remove the part ( category/category ) in the middle of all my urls.

This is the old url structure: (404s errors)
www.mywebsite.com/category-A/category-one/post-name
www.mywebsite.com/category-A/category-two/another-post-name
www.mywebsite.com/category-A/category-three/another-beautiful-post-name
etc.

This is the new structure I have (I need to redirect to this):
www.mywebsite.com/post-name
www.mywebsite.com/another-post-name
www.mywebsite.com/another-beautiful-post-name
etc.

Is there a way or do I need to thought each one by one?

Thank you

Comment: This might be a  better fit for the Stack Webmasters.

Comment: Why do just Replace the URL with [Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)

Comment: @Developer Why use a plugin when you can use code? Also, doing this in the htaccess if far quicker for the server than doing it at the WordPress level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that those directory structures stay the same, you could use the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /category-A/category-one/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /category-A/category-two/(.*) /$1
RedirectMatch 301 /category-A/category-three/(.*) /$1
```

This is a straightforward redirect. The 1st bit just looks for the relevant directory name(s) and then grabs the file name off the end.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /category-A/category-three/(.*)
```

Then it redirects to just the file name without the directories.

```
/$1
```

Note: You may need to try removing the trailing slashes &/or leading slashes to get the exact result you need. But, it should essentially be what you need.